# Firebase Cloud Functions: Promise not resolving

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having some issues with my a particular call in my cloud function that doesn't seem to be resolving correctly.

This is the code that doesn't want to resolve:

```
console.log('Getting Search Patterns');
let searchPatterns: FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot;
  try {
    searchPatterns = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('FYP_LOCATIONS')
      .get();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
 console.log(`Search Patterns Received: ${searchPatterns}`);
```

LOG:
[image]

As you can see in the log, my function runs up until the console log before the try block, then stops until the function times out. I'm not sure what it is that is causing this issue.

EDIT: I have reformatted my code by separating out each of the different parts in my cloud function into separate functions that I can call; the resulting getSearchTerms() function is as follows:

```
async function getSearchTerms(): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData[]> {
  try {
    const snapshot = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('FYP_LOCATIONS')
      .get();
    console.log('Get Returned');
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  }
}
```

This still stops at the same point in the function execution, the full function is here, this has been updated to the latest version:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as WordExtractor from 'word-extractor';
import * as textract from 'textract';
import suffixArray from './suffixArray';

// interface Location {
//   lid: string;
//   location_name: string;
//   location_type: string;
//   sentimental_value: number;
// }

// interface Context {
//   lid: string;
//   context_string: string;
//   fid: string;
// }

export const processFile = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async file => {
  const serviceAccount = require(__dirname + '/../config/serviceAccount.json');

  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://fyp-alex.firebaseio.com',
  });

  const firestore = admin.firestore();

  const fileBucket: string = file.bucket;
  const filePath: string = file.name;
  const fileDet: string = path.basename(filePath);
  const fileNameSplit: string[] = fileDet.split('.');
  const fileExt: string = fileNameSplit.pop();
  const fileName: string = fileNameSplit.join('.');
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket);
  const fileRef = bucket.file(filePath);
  const _path: string = `/tmp/${fileName}.${fileExt}`;
  console.log(`File path ${filePath}`);
  console.log('Getting Download URL');
  try {
    console.log(`Downloading to: ${_path}`);
    await fileRef.download({ destination: _path });
    console.log('File Saved');
    console.log(`Getting Details: ${_path}`);
    const text: string = await getText(_path, fileExt);
    console.log(`Processing: ${fileName}`);
    console.log('Creating Suffix Array');
    const suffix_array = suffixArray(text);
    console.log(`Suffix Array Created: ${suffix_array}`);
    console.log('Getting Search Patterns');
    const searchTerms: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData[] = await getSearchTerms();
    console.log('Search Patterns Received');
    const promises = [];
    const allContexts: Object[] = [];
    for (const searchDoc of searchTerms) {
      const searchTerm = searchDoc.location_name.toLowerCase();
      console.log(searchTerm);
      const matchedIndexes = search(text, searchTerm, suffix_array);
      const contexts = createContexts(matchedIndexes, searchDoc, text, fileName);
      allContexts.concat(contexts);
    }
    for (const context of allContexts) {
      const p = admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('FYP_CONTEXTS')
        .add(context);
      promises.push(p);
    }
    await Promise.all(promises);
    const data = {
      processed: 1,
    };
    return firestore.doc(`FYP_FILES/${fileName}`).update(data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    const data = {
      processed: 2,
    };
    return firestore.doc(`FYP_FILES/${fileName}`).update(data);
  }
});

async function getText(_path: string, fileExt: string) {
  let text: string = '';

  switch (fileExt) {
    case 'docx':
    case 'doc':
      const extractor = new WordExtractor();
      const extracted = await extractor.extract(_path);
      text = extracted.getBody();
      break;
    case 'pdf':
      break;
    case 'txt':
      textract.fromFileWithPath(_path, function(extractedError: any, string: string) {
        if (extractedError) {
          console.error(extractedError);
        }
        if (string !== null) {
          text = string;
        }
      });
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Unsupported File Type');
  }
  return text;
}

async function getSearchTerms(): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData[]> {
  try {
    const snapshot = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('FYP_LOCATIONS')
      .get();
    console.log('Get Returned');
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return [];
  }
}

function createContexts(
  matchedIndexes: number[],
  searchDoc: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData,
  text: string,
  fileName: string
) {
  console.log('Creating Contexts');
  const contexts = [];
  const searchTerm = searchDoc.location_name.toLowerCase();
  for (const index of matchedIndexes) {
    let left = index - 25;
    let right = index + searchTerm.length + 25;
    if (left < 0) {
      left = 0;
    }
    if (right > text.length) {
      right = text.length;
    }
    const context = text.substring(left, right);
    contexts.push({
      lid: searchDoc.lid,
      context_string: context,
      fid: fileName,
    });
  }
  return contexts;
}

function search(text: string, searchTerm: string, suffix_array: number[]) {
  console.log(`Beginning search for: ${searchTerm}`);
  let start = 0;
  let end = suffix_array.length;
  const matchedIndexes: Array<number> = [];

  while (start < end) {
    const mid: number = (end - 1) / 2;
    const index: number = suffix_array[mid];
    const finalIndex: number = index + searchTerm.length;
    if (finalIndex <= text.length) {
      const substring: string = text.substring(index, finalIndex);
      const match: number = searchTerm.localeCompare(substring);

      if (match === 0) {
        console.log(`Match Found at Index: ${index}`);
        matchedIndexes.push(index);
      } else if (match < 0) {
        end = mid;
      } else if (match > 0) {
        start = mid;
      }
      console.log(matchedIndexes);
    }
  }

  if (matchedIndexes.length === 0) {
    console.log(`No matches found for search term: ${searchTerm}`);
  }

  return matchedIndexes;
}
```

Hopefully the full function provides a bit more context.

I have watched Doug's videos through a few times but I am still coming up against this, I did notice that removing the await that seems to be failing (as in removing the promise all together) seemed to cause an earlier await to fail. This is indicative of it being an issue with promises later on in the function but I cannot for the life of me find the issue, I will keep trying but hopefully that provides some useful context.

Comment: Apparently you don't return the promise returned by the asynchronous `get()` operation. I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/ which explain into detail why this is a key point.

Comment: But because I'm awaiting the get() doesn't it just return the snapshot?

Comment: I have added more code to help provide more context to the issue.

Comment: There is no `return` in your two `for` loops. You should probably reorganise this part of your code in order to correctly return the promises and correctly chain those promises. Again, Doug Stevenson's videos may be of a great help.

Comment: I have reorganised the for loops and have gotten them to return some values but right now I'm still getting the same result, can you spot anything else that might be of issue? I have watched Doug's videos a few times and that has helped quite a lot but I'm still not seeing what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't letting the function know when the async operations have finished.
I would guess that you want to collect all of the async operations in an array and wait for all of them to finish before letting the function exit.

(Those youtube videos by Doug, mentioned in the comments above are quite good and do a more thorough job of explaining *why*)

ie.

```
const requests = [];
const things = [1,2,3];
for (let index = 0; index < things.length; index++) {
  const element = things[index];
  const promise = firebase.firestore().push(element);
  requests.push(promise);
}

return Promise.all(requests);
```

Comment: I have tried to do that to tidy up the promise calls but I'm still getting the same issue. I have updated the code in the question, I do feel like there's something wrong with my promises but I'm not sure.